# aws multipart upload hash problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, hash

I'm struggling to get my bash script to run a multipart upload to Amazon Glacier. My script works using 1Mb (1048576) parts, however when I try to increase the part size the hashes no longer match those returned by aws glacier. I want to increase the part size as some of my archives can be upto 1Tb in size.

For example increasing the part size to 8Mb (8388608 bytes)

```
$ dd skip=0 count=8388608 if=archive.zip of=archive_chunk.1 bs=1
```

8388608 bytes (8.4 MB) copied, 0.0122916 s, 682 MB/s

(using split instead of dd gives the same results)

```
$ openssl dgst -sha256 archive_chunk.1

SHA256(archive_chunk.1)= 8ca94b1f246d334e1576d8067b878d61c3a6b494c953518ce25c3f751c4867aa
```

Upload to aws glacier returns

```
{
    "checksum": "e5483ab34e587c69023490cfabe2b04b232890be72c0af43309fd385779184b3"
}
```

Is there anything obvious I am missing with the hash generation when I set up the size of the parts, or am I splitting the files incorrectly? I have tried a range of sizes (64Mb=67108864 and 256Mb=268435456) and all fail to match the aws hashes.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The [tree hash algorithm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations.html) *requires* that the hash be calculated beginning in 1MB chunks, regardless of the part size.  Have you take this into account?  If you do an 8 MB upload, you have to run 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 hash operations to get the hash of each 8 MB chunk.  Have you taken that into account?

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. So the hash for each individual uploaded part has to be calculated as a tree hash? I was under the (perhaps misguided!) impression that the tree hash was calculated at the end of the uploads from all the hashes of the individual parts? I'm going to try your suggestion and see if I can get the hashes to match

Comment: No, the tree hash is calculated at the end, as you said -- but it is not from the hashes of the upload parts.  It *has* to be calculated against blocks of exactly 1MB each, regardless of upload part size.  Your code works with 1MB upload parts but not other part sizes, essentially by coincidence, because you happened to have chosen the 1MB upload part size.

Comment: Shouldn't the openssl dgst hash of a single uploaded part be expected to match the aws hash returned from that single upload? (It does for a 1Mb chunk). To be clear - this is before I get to the final tree hashing step.

Comment: I am so sorry... I was operating partially from memory and it's been a little while since I wrote Glacier API code.  The part tree hashing is one reason the part size for Glacier uploads must be exactly 1MiB multiplied by an integer power of 2... so valid part sizes are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16... and yes, you do the tree hash on each part, so yes, openssl dgst would only agree at the 1 MiB chunk size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool to compute the tree hash: https://github.com/erichmenge/treehash

`gem install treehash`

then just

`treehash filename`

Comment: I believe it does, I've used it for files of a few GBs